# how to delete a minus sign from a string in swift

Tags: string, swift

I have an app that calculates the difference between two dates. If the user enters a Start Date that is later than the End Date, the result is a negative. This is fine. However, the string that my app produces contains two minus signs. I want to eliminate the second minus sign, so that instead of saying "-17 weeks + - 4 days" it says "-17 weeks + 4 days".

[image]

I need to remove the second minus sign from the result. I know that this is achieved through string manipulation but I don't know precisely how to do it. I would need to check first that the outputted string has a negative value, before implementing the string manipulation. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful.

The method where I would need to implement this string manipulation to delete the 2nd minus sign is as follows:

```
@IBAction func calculateWeeksAndDays(sender: UIButton) {

    if startDateTextField.text == "" || endDateTextField == "" {

        let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "Please Select an End Date!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {

    let start = String(startDateTextField.text!)
    let end = String(endDateTextField.text!)
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"



        guard let startDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(start), endDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(end) else {

            return
 }


    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components([.Day], fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: [])
    let days = components.day
    let weeks = components.day / 7
    let weeksanddays = days % 7
    let newString = "\(weeks) weeks + \(weeksanddays) days"
    resultWeeksAndDays.text = newString
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `abs()`, it returns the absolute value, this is useful for the `string`.

```
let newString = "\(weeks) weeks + \(abs(weeksanddays)) days"
```

---

Check if something is negative:

```
if weeks < 0 {
    // do stuffs
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with `and` rather than `+` in the output string you could use `NSDateComponentsFormatter`. It handles the sign issue automatically.

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components([.Day], fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: [])

let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .Full
formatter.allowedUnits = [.Day]
let onlyDaysString = formatter.stringFromDateComponents(components)
formatter.allowedUnits = [.Day, .WeekOfMonth]
let daysAndWeeksString = formatter.stringFromDateComponents(components)
```